# How to Add Icon to Button (Tizen Wearable) + Equivalent of RelativeLayout in Tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

Good day. I'm trying to develop a simple Tizen (wearable) app. So, my current goal is to make a button that has a 'plus' icon. I've created a single UI Layout project.

So, this is the code for the button.

```
<button align_v="fill" visible="true" weight_v="1" pack_h="49" weight_h="1" align_h="fill" pack_w="210" disable="false" pack_x="290" pack_y="364" style="default" id="button1" text="Button">
```

Usually, when creating Android apps, we do this:

```
android:src="@mipmap/baseline_plus_alt_black_24"
```

'src' attribute is not allowed for buttons in Tizen apparently. 
Is there a workaround?

How do we do something like this in Tizen?

PS: Does anyone have any idea the equivalent of a RelativeLayout(android) in Tizen?

Appreciate it folks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 application model for Tizen Wearable device.

- Native(C)
- Web
- C#

I recommend to use C#. Tizen supports Xamarin Forms and [Tizen.CircularUI](https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.CircularUI/) for developing UI.

[Installing Visual Studio Tools for Tizen](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/visual-studio-tools-tizen/installing-visual-studio-tools-tizen)

Comment: [ImageButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton) of Xamarin Forms...